# Ubuntu Software Center Stuck in the Middle of Installation

Tags: software-center

I tried to install team viewer today and the Ubuntu software center seems to be stuck in the middle of the installation.  It's been like this for a few hours.  Is there a safe way to cancel the installation or kill the installation process?

Answer (score 1):

What I would usually do is just to reboot the machine, then re-install again